# Copying files to a local/host directory

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to copy files from a container to a local/host directory. Running my experiments on minikube. Tried starting minikube with a mount as: `minikube mount /tmp/export:/data/export` and it still does not work.

I have a single pod, that upon startup runs a simple script:

```
timeout --signal=SIGINT 10s clinic bubbleprof -- node index.js >> /tmp/clinic.output.log && \
  cp -R `grep "." /tmp/clinic.output.log | tail -1 | grep -oE '[^ ]+$'`* /data/export/ && \
echo "Finished copying clinic run generated files"
```

Once my script finishes its run, the container dies. This happens because `bash` is the process with `PID` 1. I don't mind this. My problem is that `/tmp/export` is empty, after the files should have been copied out.

My pod yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: clinic-testapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: clinic-testapp
    image: username/container-image:0.0.11
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: clinic-storage
      mountPath: /data/export
  volumes:
  - name: clinic-storage
    hostPath:
     path: /tmp/export
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please advise.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but why is `kubectl cp` not an option?

Comment: It is not an option because I need to copy from a script running inside the container. Further, I want to understand what I am doing wrong. Else, I would mount an NFS client and not use `kubectl` either way.

Comment: keep in mind that minikube is a virtual maschine. so you have to access your temp dir in the minikube machine.